# Alertcontroller with a button or image

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I need to show an alert with a button or image in it. I have tried changing the alert height and adding the button, but I can't make it work in Swift.

Also, I think that the App Store could reject my app for that kind of "hacking".

I have researched a lot, but I can't find a library or a pod that helps with this behavior.

Any ideas?

[image: Alertcontroller with a button or image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some custom alert views you can implement

- https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview
- https://github.com/dogo/SCLAlertView
- https://github.com/Friend-LGA/LGAlertView

Swift

- https://github.com/codestergit/SweetAlert-iOS
- https://github.com/stakes/JSSAlertView

Comment: Do you know a swift version of any of this custom alerts?